# Как подчеркнуть при письме

Tags: дополнение

Если одно и то же слово является и дополнением и обстоятельством, то как его подчеркнуть при письме?

Comment: Примеры приведите, пожалуйста. Пока не очень понятно, о чем речь и зачем вообще что-то подчеркивать.

Answer (score 2):

Это явление называется СИНКРЕТИЗМ. Слово подчеркивается дважды, одно под другим. Например: веранда во дворе. Сначала подчёркиваем как обстоятельство (где?) штрих-пунктиром. Ниже - как определение (какой?) - волнистой линией.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что вопрос об этом... Подчеркивание волнистыми и прочими - это средняя школа, какой уж тут синкретизм,.